# bluetooth earbuds show up as two devices

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

my Bluetooth earbuds show up as two devices on my windows laptop, headphones, and headset. on top of the headset device has drastically lower audio quality and some applications, like discord and zoom, will only use the headset device, regardless of what i tell it to do in settings and i cant hear the sounds going to separate devices.

anyone have a fix for this? new Bluetooth drivers? Anything? thanks.

for reference these are the ear buds i have: [https://www.amazon.com/Soundcore-Bluetooth-Headphones-Waterproof-Sweatproof/dp/B08SKLL4GC/ref=sr_1_4?crid=92558JDQRMIJ&dchild=1&keywords=soundcore+sprint&qid=1628937938&sprefix=sound+core+spr%2Caps%2C226&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SKLL4GC) and i am running windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and just how Bluetooth works. Bluetooth is relatively low bandwidth and this is the concession that has to be made.

For just audio out you can use the headphones profile and audio is high quality because all the bandwidth is in one direction.

If you need to use the microphone then bandwidth has to be shared between audio going to the headset and microphone audio coming from the headset. The result is much poorer audio in both directions.

If you need high quality sound out then you cannot use the microphone, if you need the microphone then you cannot have high quality audio.

I tend to use a separate microphone and avoid using the "headset" whenever possible.

Comment: Also, in case anyone is wondering about Bluetooth 5: While it does have higher bandwidth, it does not define a profile for bi-directional high quality audio. So nothing changes.

Comment: I would love to do that, but it wont let me. regardless of the discord settings I set discord uses headset and refuses to use anything else. even if I disable headset in windows sound settings it won't send any sound to headphones.